# Self-referencing Lyapunov equation

Tags: matrix-equations

Let $A$ be a square, Hurwitz matrix.
The Lyapunov-like equation

$$
AP + PA^T = -P
$$

is trivially solved by $P=0$, where $0$ here has the same size of $A$.

Can we find positive-definite solutions too?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Move $-P$ to the LHS, then introduce identity matrix factor $I$ to collect the $P$ factors with either $A$ or $A^T$. Then you'll get a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation) without any "self-references". Using uniqueness theorem for it (see the link), you can check whether the solution you find is the unique solution.

Comment: That leaves the RHS to zero, and then the solver returns a zero solution.

Comment: @Antonio right, and now I refer you to uniqueness theorem for Sylvester equation (see the link in my answer).